# Is the US president guaranteed to receive a Presidential Library, no matter how his term ends?

Tags: united-states, president

In the modern era, US Presidents are entitled to numerous perks after their departure from office, including a [Presidential Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_library), 24/7 protection by the Secret Service, a generous pension, etc.

What happens to most of these perks is already explained in the question "[If a president is impeached and removed from power, do they lose all benefits usually afforded to presidents when they leave office?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61612/if-a-president-is-impeached-and-removed-from-power-do-they-lose-all-benefits-us)". But what this question not answers is whether or not they receive a presidential library.

Are there any qualifications for receiving a presidential library? If a president leaves the office voluntarily or is impeached, will he still get one no matter what?

Comment: FWIW, here is a link to [Richard Nixon's presidential library website](https://www.nixonlibrary.gov/). But from your link: `The Act **encouraged** other Presidents to donate their historical materials` (emphasis mine) and `In each case, funds from private and non-federal public sources provided the funds to build the library`. And it seems than Trump can certainly fund himself one, if he has something to put in it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a president is impeached and removed from power, do they lose all benefits usually afforded to presidents when they leave office?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61612/if-a-president-is-impeached-and-removed-from-power-do-they-lose-all-benefits-us)

Comment: @Charles1267 I reduced this question to ask only about the presidential library. This aspect is not addressed at all by the question you proposed as a duplicate, but it is answered here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering this will require going through each benefit one at a time. To get the ball rolling, here is the details for the presidential libraries system.

### Presidential Libraries

A President is not guaranteed to receive a Presidential Library or collection memorializing their time in office. The creation of these archives and collections is at the discretion of the Archivist of the National Archives and Records Administration (See 3(a) of the [Presidential Libraries Act](https://www.archives.gov/presidential-libraries/laws/1986-act.html)).  Additionally, the initial funding and collection materials are all required to be donated:

> A Presidential Library is constructed with private or non-Federal funds donated to non-profit organizations established usually for the express purpose of building a Presidential Library and supporting its programs.
>
> Some Libraries have also received construction and development funding from state and/or local governments. ([Presidential Library FAQ](https://www.archives.gov/presidential-libraries/about/faqs.html))

However, the law makes few qualifications about which presidents this applies to. The relevent statute says:

> ...any President who takes oath of office as President for the first time on or after January 20, 1985 (Sec(4) of the [Presidential Libraries Act](http://ny%20President%20who%20takes%20oath%20of%20office%20as%20President%20for%20the%20first%20time%20on%20or%20after%20January%2020,%201985))