# If a president is impeached and removed from power, do they lose all benefits usually afforded to presidents when they leave office?

Tags: united-states, president, impeachment

It is my understanding that there are a number of benefits bestowed to presidents when they leave office.  These include a lucrative pension, $1 million travel budget per year, personal protection etc.  Can someone clarify what these benefits are and whether or not presidents lose them if they are impeached and removed from power.

Comment: Then there's the question of whether Pence will get these benefits if he's the President for 20 minutes.

Comment: @J.G. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61618/would-mike-pence-become-president-if-trump-was-impeached-and-removed-from-office

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The benefits granted to former presidents are set out in the appropriately-named [Former Presidents Act](https://www.archives.gov/about/laws/former-presidents.html) passed in 1958. This act entitles former presidents to a rate of pay equal to that of a head of an executive department for the rest of their life (paragraph a), office staff (paragraph b), office space (paragraph c), a spousal allowance after the former president's death (paragraph e), and  an annual allowance of up to $1 million of travel and security related expenses for themselves, and $500 thousand for their spouse (paragraph g).

However, paragraph f of the above Act defines a former president as:

> a person--
>
> 1. who shall have held the office of President of the United States of America;
> 2. **whose service in such office shall have terminated other than by removal pursuant to section 4 of article II of the Constitution of the
>    United States of America**; and
> 3. who does not then currently hold such office.

Therefore, if impeached and removed from office, a president would not receive any of the above benefits.

On the other hand, Secret Service protection for life after leaving office is granted by [18 U.S. Code § 3056](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/3056), which contains no such provision. Even if impeached and removed from office, it seems that an ex-president would still receive this protection, if not declined.

The right to a state funeral is not enshrined in law, only policy. The military pamphlet found [here](https://www.secnav.navy.mil/doni/Directives/05000%20General%20Management%20Security%20and%20Safety%20Services/05-300%20Manpower%20Personnel%20Support/5360.1.pdf) mentions those eligible for a state funeral, and makes no mention of impeachment and conviction disqualifying a former president from this entitlement. State funerals must be ordered by presidential proclamation, so in this sense, there doesn't appear to be anything legally guaranteeing or denying a state funeral to a former president removed from office in this way.

Nevertheless, after their death, they *are* entitled to have U.S. flags on federal buildings flown at half-staff for thirty days, in accordance with [4 U.S. Code § 7 (m)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/4/7).

Comment: Technically this means that a President could resign at the very last moment and still keep their benefits, since their office would be terminated voluntarily, similar to what Nixon did.

Comment: How do those amounts account for inflation?

Comment: @DKNguyen unless the law itself included a provision for inflation, it wouldn't adjust except by passing a new law overriding the old amounts.  And inflation wasn't a big concern in 1958.  There's no possible way that the amounts set in 1958 would still be appropriate today, so it's definitely a mystery.

Comment: What about funeral benefits (i.e. state funeral) for a former President?

Comment: @MarkRansom Subsection (g), providing $1.5 million annually for travel and security to former Presidents+spouses *not* under Secret Service protection, was added in [a 1995 act](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/103/hr4539/text) that also limited Secret Service protection for former Presidents after Clinton to 10 years. In 2013, lifetime Secret Service protection was reinstated, applying retroactively to G. W. Bush, but subsection (g) remains. I think the only way to get that money now is to decline Secret Service protection.

Comment: What happens if the Senate doesn't get round to voting on the impeachment until after 12 noon on the 20th, so that his service in office ends normally but he is then retroactively convicted?

Comment: @DrSheldon added a section on this :)

Comment: @MikeScott by my reading, the president would not have been removed from office by the impeachment process, so they would remain a former president by the definition used in para f.

Comment: So a US president could resign after 1 minute in the office and still get all the benefits? Sounds like a nice plan for a rich and safe retirement with lots of traveling.

Comment: @Michael pretty sure the cost of being elected is higher than the life-time payout of that fund.

Comment: @Erik How much do they actually pay out of pocket to fund their campaign though? Isn't it mostly funded by errr...fundraising?

Comment: All the plans for gaming this law surely miss the fact that congress can change the law (and maybe even make the change retroactive) if they're sufficiently annoyed by the gaming. If congress doesn't want [unnamed hypothetical President] to get the benefits, it is in their power to do so.

Comment: @Erik ... Politicians at the federal level in the US do not pay out of pocket to fund their campaigns.  The corporate class, through SuperPacs, fund these campaigns and write it off as an expense.  It's a corporatocracy, not a democracy.

Comment: @MikeScott One of the biggest advantages of impeaching after the fact is it can stop him from running again.

Comment: @Styxsksu Technically, I’m not sure that it can stop him from running. It can stop him from winning.

Comment: @MikeScott at what point between "running" and "winning" would an ineligible candidate be stopped?

Comment: @Will Inauguration, I would imagine.  Whether the runner-up, Vice President elect or Speaker of the House would become President, I’m not sure.

Comment: @Styxsksu, the Senate would have to be explicit about Trump not being able to hold public office again. If they just remove him from office, he could run again. https://www.politifact.com/article/2019/nov/06/could-donald-trump-be-impeached-removed-and-then-r/

Comment: @MikeScott for an inauguration Congress would have to certify the results. That certification would surely be open to a SCOTUS challenge. Realistically there are obstacles way further back down the line affecting the individual electoral votes that Congress would be counting, and almost certainly they wouldn't make it onto enough ballots to be reasonably considered to be "running". Anyhow, I think my point is if the outcome you're inviting people to cast votes for is constitutionally out of the question I'm not sure it counts as running anyway.